# Why does my prolog file only give me errors?

Tags: prolog

I have the following .pl file:

```
parent(Peter,Anne).
parent(Peter,Mark).

parent(Zara,Anne).
parent(Zara,Mark).


parent(Beatrice,Andrew).
parent(Beatrice,Sarah).

parent(Eugenie,Andrew).
parent(Eugenie,Sarah).


parent(Louise,Edward).
parent(Louise,Sophie).

parent(James,Edward).
parent(James,Sophie).

father(X,Y) :- male(Y),parent(Y,X).
mother(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(X,Y).
son(X,Y) :- male(X),parent(Y,X).
daughter(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(Y,X).
grandfather(X,Y) :- male(X),parent(X,Somebody),parent(Somebody,Y).
aunt(X,Y) :- female(X),sister(X,Mom),mother(Mom,Y).
aunt(X,Y) :- female(X),sister(X,Dad),father(Dad,Y).
sister(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(Par,X),parent(Par,Y), X \= Y.
uncle(X,Y) :- brother(X,Par),parent(Par,Y).
cousin(X,Y) :- uncle(Unc, X),father(Unc,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y).
ancestor(X,Y) :- parent(X,Somebody),ancestor(Somebody,Y).
brother(X,Y) :-  male(X),parent(Somebody,X),parent(Somebody,Y), X \= Y.
```

When I run it, I get the following errors:

```
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:4: warning: singleton variables [Peter,Anne] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:5: warning: singleton variables [Peter,Mark] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:7: warning: singleton variables [Zara,Anne] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:8: warning: singleton variables [Zara,Mark] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:11: warning: singleton variables [Beatrice,Andrew] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:12: warning: singleton variables [Beatrice,Sarah] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:14: warning: singleton variables [Eugenie,Andrew] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:15: warning: singleton variables [Eugenie,Sarah] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:18: warning: singleton variables [Louise,Edward] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:19: warning: singleton variables [Louise,Sophie] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:21: warning: singleton variables [James,Edward] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:22: warning: singleton variables [James,Sophie] for parent/2
/home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg compiled, 36 lines read - 5049 bytes written, 10 ms
warning: /home/cg/root/3832463/main.pg:1: user directive caused exception: error(existence_error(procedure,main/0),load/1)
| ?- 
uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:1 (char:5) . or operator expected after expression'),read_term/3)
| ?-
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your argument starts with a capital it is a variable. If it is lowercase it is an atom.

Change:

```
parent(Peter,Anne).
parent(Peter,Mark).
```

to:

```
parent(peter,anne).
parent(peter,mark).
```

Comment: I tried running a query `setof(grandchild(elizabeth,_),List).` to get a list of all of Elizabeth's children, but I get `uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:1 (char:19) , or ) expected'),read_term/3)` as a response. Any advice?

Comment: @tushariyer - What is the arity of `setof`? When you find that you'll have a big hint.

Comment: `setof/3` needs three arguments: the pattern to extract from the goal, the goal itself, and the destination for the result list. Try `setof(Child, grandchild(elizabeth, Child), Children)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

People names are usually capitalized.
In Prolog, since a symbol starting with an uppercase letter is a variable, you should quote them:

```
parent('Peter','Anne').
etc...
```